# OS.rename() not working with tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, module

Folks I'm trying to make a tool which gets user path and file name in one entry and new file name with path in another entry, My aim is to use `os.rename(oldname, newname)` to rename the given file, but its throwing me some error.

My code

```
from tkinter import *
import os

def Rename_Function(*args):
    os.rename(oldname2,newname)
    oldname.set(oldname)#"Renamed Successfully !!! ")


root = Tk()
root.title("MyPython App")
root.geometry("250x250+100+50")

oldname = StringVar()
oldname2= StringVar()
newname= StringVar()
Title1 = Label(root,text="FileName (with path):")
Title1.grid(row=0, column=0)
Oldfilename = Entry(root, textvariable=oldname2)
Oldfilename.grid(row=0, column=1)
Title2 = Label(root, text="New Filename:")
Title2.grid(row=1, column=0)
Newfilename = Entry(root, textvariable=newname)
Newfilename.grid(row=1, column=1)
RenameButton = Button(root, text="RENAME MY FILE", command=Rename_Function)
RenameButton.grid(row=3,columnspan=2, sticky="NWES")
FinalOutput = Label(textvariable=oldname)
FinalOutput.grid(row=4, columnspan=2, sticky = "NWES")
root.mainloop()
```

[image: This is how the tool looks]

[image]

I'm getting the above error when I click the button, 
Can someone guide me how to make it work.

I have a doubt that `os.rename()` function should be accessed in some other way since its another module's function. Since I'm learner I don't have any clue how to use them effeciently. Please guide me and explain me so that I would understand this concept better.

Comment: You are passing a `StringVar()` when you should be passing a native string. Convert to string before calling your rename function.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan can you tell me how to do it with example line for one `StringVar()` you mean using str() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand upon what @SuperSaiyan said in the comment(s).

You are using a `StringVar`, which has the method `.get()` available to it. When you pass the variable which is set to this stringvar you are just passing the reference to this object. You need to actually use the `.get()` method to get the string.

e.g. - `oldname2.get()`

Also, for selecting the path you could just use a filedialog, and use `os.path.splitext` to get the base path + entry in the renaming widget to use as the second parameter with `os.rename`

Comment: oh Man Thanks a lot! Got it now is there any link where I can learn more about get and set methods

Comment: Here's one site that has a lot of tkinter stuff http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm

Answer (score 1):

You are using `StringVar`, whereas `rename` needs Strings. Use `oldname.get()`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

def rename(oldname, oldname2, newname):
    os.rename(oldname2.get(),newname.get())
    oldname.set("Renamed Successfully !!! ")

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("MyPython App")
    root.geometry("250x250+100+50")
    oldname = tk.StringVar()
    oldname2= tk.StringVar()
    newname= tk.StringVar()
    tk.Label(root, text="FileName (with path):").grid(row=0, column=0)
    tk.Entry(root, textvariable=oldname2).grid(row=0, column=1)
    tk.Label(root, text="New Filename:").grid(row=1, column=0)
    tk.Entry(root, textvariable=newname).grid(row=1, column=1)
    tk.Button(root, text="RENAME MY FILE", command=lambda: rename(oldname, oldname2, newname)).grid(row=3,columnspan=2, sticky="NWES")
    tk.Label(textvariable=oldname).grid(row=4, columnspan=2, sticky = "NWES")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what the answer 20 minutes ago said!